# Install python-dev with no root permission

Tags: python, redhat

I am trying to install this software https://github.com/phoenixding/tbsp/ but it needs python-dev. However, I don't have root permission

I have tried some ways including create virtualenv but there is not specific answer how to install this python-dev.

My Linux system is RedHat

Here is the code:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Here is the error

```
pyBigWig.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```